# Have a reference in memory of the image taken

Tags: android, caching, photo

im coding a photo app, im a little new on this of performance and optimization, a common thing that i noticed is that when i take the photo from my app but i dont submit it , it will save to my sd card , this is allright because i get the reference of the photo in the sd card and then i can submit the photo, but this is what i want to do.

I dont want the user to have photos that he dosnt submit, i mean, if you take a bunch of photos but you only want the last one, why you need to have in the sd all the other photos you dont want.

I just want to save that taked photo in memory cache, so when i take it it only generates 1 image, with the reference in the cache, not in the sd, so if i take another one it will be replaced.

i dont know if i explain myself, i hope someone can help me solve this proble just giving me some resources from where i can get orientated.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i press a button and the photo uploads to firebase storage

Comment: i dont want to save all the photos that i dont press submit in my phone, i just want to save the one that i will upload, no more than that, thats why i need to cache it and not saving all the taken photos directly to the sd card